# Asymptotic analysis of a double sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, asymptotics

Let $\{a_{m,j}\}_{m,j \in \Bbb N} \in \Bbb R_+$ such that for each $m$ $$b_m=\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{m,j}<\infty$$
and
$$\lim_{j \to \infty} \frac{a_{m+1,j}}{a_{m,j}}=0$$

I would like to know if is true that:

Exist $k \in \Bbb N$ such that $b_{m+1}<b_m$ for each $m>k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** Take for instance $a_{1,j} = \frac{1}{j^2}$ for all $j\geq 1$, and, for $m\geq 1$,
$$
a_{m+1,j} = \begin{cases}
\frac{a_{m,j}}{j} & \text{ if } j\geq 2\\
b_m+1 & \text{ if } j=1
\end{cases}
$$
Then your assumptions are satisfied, yet $b_{m+1} > a_{m+1,1} = b_m+1 > b_m$ for all $m$.

The issue is that the assumption that $\lim_{j \to \infty} \frac{a_{m+1,j}}{a_{m,j}}=0$ is only an asymptotic guarantee, and does not tell you anything about the first terms — which can do whatever they want.